# How can I find out what class(es) a method is in, in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

How can I find out what class(es) a method is defined in, in Ruby?

For example lets say that I wanted to know what classes implement the `to_s` method. How would I do that using the `ri` command?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
~$ ri

Enter the method name you want to look up.
You can use tab to autocomplete.
Enter a blank line to exit.

>> to_s

= .to_s

(from gem actionpack-3.1.0.rc6)
=== Implementation from ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::RemoteIpGetter
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_s()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


(from gem actionpack-3.1.0.rc6)
=== Implementation from ActionView::FileSystemResolver
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_s()

------------------------------------------------------------------------------


(from gem actionpack-3.1.0.rc6)
=== Implementation from ActionView::FixtureResolver
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  to_s()
```

Answer (score 2):

EDIT | This answer makes no sense since you edited your question ;)  Out of context it did.

Terribly in-efficient approach.  I can't see why you'd need this, personally:

```
class ClassEnumerator
  def each(&block)
    ObjectSpace.each_object(Class, &block)
  end

  include Enumerable
end

ClassEnumerator.new.select { |klass| klass.instance_methods.include?(:merge) }
```

This should find all classes implementing `#merge`.

```
pry(main)> ClassEnumerator.new.select { |klass| klass.instance_methods.include?(:merge) }
=> [OptionParser::CompletingHash,
 OptionParser::OptionMap,
 Hash,
 Gem::Dependency,
 Psych::Omap,
 Psych::Set,
 URI::MailTo,
 URI::LDAPS,
 URI::LDAP,
 CodeRay::CaseIgnoringWordList,
 CodeRay::WordList,
 URI::HTTPS,
 URI::HTTP,
 URI::FTP,
 URI::Generic]
pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also type `ri METHOD_NAME` see `man ri`